# "Cannot resolve method ... " after inserted app indexing by accident

Tags: android

If you Inserted app indexing API code by mistake and an error like "Cannot resolve method ... " is popping up but cannot reverse it.

Answer (score 3):

Try **sync project with gradle files** under Tools > Android

[image]